# skip auto increment in sequelize when an error is occur

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, auto-increment

i have a problem when i create a record in mysql with sequelize and give me error for example for unique constraint and last auto increment id is 1 after giving error and then submit successfully id is become 3
Thanks for your advise

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is issue of my question?

Comment: You need to provide some relevant code, and format your question more clearly..i just don't understand it :D

Comment: auto increment must set one by one for first record is 1 and for second 2 .....
but when insert a record and give me unique constraint error that record wont be save but id is increment without save record

Comment: Why do you want to skip numbers in an autoIncrement column?

Comment: i dont need but because sequelize that occur

Comment: It means you're forming your models/migrations incorrectly. If you don't want a column to be AI, then set it to autoIncrement: false. Then, you will need to supply the numeric ID yourself. Maybe show the definition of the problematic table, it will be easier to help you...

Comment: when i  enter a duplicate data into unique column it also increase the column id (auto increment) but i dont want this happen

Comment: Validate the entry even before create it. Check uniqueness and throw error from application, before creating the entry.

Comment: thank you @RatulSharker